Getting error { code: 403,message: 'SenderId mismatch', status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',details: [ [Object] ] } when sending fcm http v1 pushnotification
I am upgrading aws sns legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API to FCM http v1 api. for that in my lambda function (in nodejs) added below code.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { GoogleAuth } = require('google-auth-library');
const axios = require('axios');
const serviceAccount = require('../../service-account.json');
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  credentials: serviceAccount,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging']
});
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)


});

async function getAccessToken() {
      const client = await auth.getClient();
      const token = await client.getAccessToken();
      console.log("token ",token.token)
      return token.token;
}
    
async function sendFcmMessage(message) {
      const token = await getAccessToken();
    
      try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projct_id/messages:send',
        {
          message: message
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      );
    
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error sending message:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
      }
}


const sentmessage = {
        token: deviceToken,
        notification: {
          title: 'Test Notification',
          body: realDeviceName + ' ' + txtLevel + ': ' + txtValue, // "body" can be used as alias, is converted to "message"
        }
    };

sendFcmMessage(sentmessage).catch(console.error);

with the above code i am getting { code: 403,message: 'SenderId mismatch', status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',details: [ [Object] ] }.
Please let me know if anyone have idea of this error. Thank you.

Here's the updated code. Error is resolved by ensuring proper axios configuration.
async function sendFcmMessage(params) {

  // call the function with params to make it dynamic

  const token = await getAccessToken();

  try {
    const data = {
      message: {
        token: token,
        notification: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
        }
      }
    };

    const config = {
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/abillion-analytics/messages:send',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: data,
    };
    const response = await axios(config);
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log('App Notification Sent');
  console.log('Successfully sent message:', response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
  }
}


sendFcmMessage().catch(console.error);


I tried with above code but still error persist.

please check it once again coz i got the same error by running your code and its get resolved by the above code and successfully fired the notification
